# How to link two containers using docker-compose

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

At the moment I have two containers which I build from an image and then link the two:

For example:

```
#mysql
docker build -t my/mysql docker-mysql
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name mysql -d my/mysql:latest

#webapp
docker build -t my/tomcat:7.0 tomcat/7.0
docker run -d --link mysql --name tomcat7 my/tomcat:7.0
```

Since I'm linking the `webapp` container with `mysql` container, the `webapp` container gets a `MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR` environment variable created. I use this environment variable to then connect to the mysql database in my `jdbc` string.

All of this works fine but now I'd like to use `docker-compose` so that everything can be built and ran from one command.

However, while playing with docker-compose I'm noticing that it prefixes `docker_` to the image name and furthermore deprecates the `link` option.

**Question**

How would the above build/run commands translate to docker-compose yml file such that the webapp container can connect to the mysql container for jdbc.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add an `alias` attribute in the compose yml. The following is taken from the docs the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links) and is a very short example

```
web:
  links:
   - db
   - db:database
   - redis
```

That compose snippet defines a `web` container which has to be linked to the db and redis containers and it also adds the `db` container with the alias `database.

In you case, I think the yml for the tomcat container would look something like this

```
mysql:
  image: my/mysql:latest
  ports:
  - "3306:3306"

tomcat7:
  image: my/tomcat:7.0
  links:
   - mysql
```

Bear in mind that the tomcat container is not exposing any ports!

Comment: I think you need to use the `build:` config, not `image:`, unless it is pre-built

Comment: True! I assumed that the images would be built in a different step as there's no reference the their docker files on the original question (so it looks like both are on different folders, but that's not clear).

Comment: `docker build` will by default grab the `Dockerfile` in the build-context

Comment: I'm reading up on `docker network`. Is this scenario an apt case to use it?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a rough translation to a docker-compose.

Note that docker-compose tags it's own images, so say you made a `mysql` image in a directory named `test`, then the container name would turn into `test_mysql_1`. The 1 is appended on the end because you can scale up multiple containers using docker-compose.

This file also assumes this file-structure

```
├── docker-mysql
│   └── Dockerfile
├── tomcat
│   └── 7.0
│       └── Dockerfile
└── docker-compose.yml
```

---

```
version: '2'
services:
    mysql:
        build:
            context: "./docker-mysql"
        hostname: mysql
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
    webapp:
        build:
            context: "./tomcat/7.0"
        hostname: tomcat7
        links:
            - mysql
```

Comment: if a `mysql` images in directory `test` is turned to `test_mysql_1`, then how would someone handle the case where an image depends on another image. For example: `FROM mycustom/ubuntu`. Should that be run outside of docker compose then?

Comment: I haven't figured that one out. Personally, I build all base images before running `docker-compose up` and use the `image:` configuration (as mentioned in the other answer) for the respective `image:tag`

Comment: The `hostname:` key/values here are unnecessary, you can remove them.

Comment: Yes, the case of building chains of images is not handled by compose, building it outside of compose is a good option.